# What is the technical term for this data in Python?

Tags: python, class

I am reviewing some code and looking at some of the classes. Within the class (for instance class ResourceBaseSchema), what is the technical term for the items id, private, canRead, canWrite, owner etc... I want to learn more about them, but I'm not sure what to search.

My experience so far with classes only covers attributes, which tends to be in the form of self.attribute.

Thanks

```
import json
from requests import Request
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydoc import locate
from typing import List, Optional
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime

SCHEMAS = {}

class ResourceBaseSchema(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]
    private: Optional[bool]
    canRead: Optional[List[str]]
    canWrite: Optional[List[str]]
    owner: Optional[str]
    anonymousComments: Optional[bool]
    comments: Optional[List[str]]
    createdAt: Optional[str]
    updatedAt: Optional[str]
```

Comment: Those are attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are **class attributes**. They exist regardless of the **objects** created from the `class`. Attributes defined in the `__init__` method, or in other methods, in the form `self.attribute` are **object attributes**. They exist only when an **object** is created from the `class` and they belong to that specific **object**.

In practical use you can access **class attributes** from a **class reference** that has not been instantiated like this:

```
class.attribute
```

Notice that the class has not been instantiated i.e `class()`

Here's another example:

```
class test:
    class_attribute = 1
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.object_attribute = 2

# Accessing class attribute
a = test.class_attribute

# Accessing object attribute
b = test().object_attribute
```

`self` in python **classes** refers to the instance of the `class`. So it's only available upon instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

They are class attributes (AKA [class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-class-variable)), but more specifically, they're **fields**. See the [Pydantic docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/):

> ```
> from pydantic import BaseModel
>
> class User(BaseModel):
>     id: int
>     name = 'Jane Doe'
> ```
>
> `User` here is a model with two fields `id` which is an integer and is required, and `name` which is a string and is not required (it has a default value).

This is similar to dataclasses in the standard library:

> The [`dataclass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass) decorator examines the class to find `field`s. A `field` is defined as class variable that has a [type annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-variable-annotation).

Comment: P.S. I'm not an expert at this so correct me if I'm wrong.